# Regenerate Resources.Designer.cs in WinRT Universal Application

Tags: c#, localization, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am working on an application that was migrated from Windows Runtime 8 to Windows Runtime 8.1 as a universal app with existing translations.  The folder after conversion was named Resources rather than strings.  This seemed to function until we tried to update the Resource.resw file for each language.  No matter what I do Resources.designer.cs will not regenerate.

Things I have tried...

1. Update all language resw file by coping over existing files with new versions.  Clean and Rebuild.  Resources.Designer.cs is not regenerated.
2. Update the Resources.resw file in the Resources folder (not under a language, I assume this is a default language file or a design time language file).  Clean and Rebuild.  Resources.Designer.cs is not regenerated.
3. Revert back from source control.  Clean.  Tried 1 and 2 again in various ways.  Cant find how to run custom tool as I remember doing in the past.
4. Rename resources folder to Strings.  Clean and Rebuild.  Resources.Designer.cs is not regenerated.

Now I start really reading and I am seeing posts that seem to indicate that the custom tool isn't available to a shared project and/or that keeping translations in a shared project requires some different approach.  Unfortunately these posts are somewhat vague or seem like they should not be necessary.

Some posts show PRIResource build type of the Resources.resw file as being able to define the CustomTool property.  My files are set to PRIResource but I do not have an option to define the Custom Tool in properties.

What is the correct approach to use language resources from the Shared project?

Is there a way to the regenerate Resources.Designer.cs file for a shared project?

Thanks!

Comment: So the only solution I have found is to move the Resources/Strings in each project (Store and Phone) and then when the Resource.resw file is set as a PRIResource I can set the Custom Tool property to ResWFileCodeGenerator.  I also did update to the latest version of ResWFileCodeGenerator from codeplex but I doubt that part was necessary.

Comment: So this runs into problems with the approach used from WinRt 8.0.  There is a path where it works but it is a significant change.  The problem because that I could no longer bind xaml strings.  It seems with 8.1 you cannot use the same approach.  Though it seems since 8.1 will not regenerate resources.Designer.cs it is pretty safe to add the references yourself if it is a minor update.  This will work for now until I am ready to change the approach completely.